# What is android game rotation vector's reference

Tags: android, vector, rotation

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-gamerot)

"The game rotation vector sensor is identical to the Rotation Vector Sensor, except it does not use the geomagnetic field. Therefore the Y axis does not point north but instead to some other reference."

So what exactly is the "some other reference"? Is it possible to set the game rotation vector's reference to some arbitrary rotation?

Answer (score 0):

some other reference is not specified as it's not important, it's just something else, some random value.

The idea is that this sensor feels the changes and allows you to find the delta within your previous query.

For example you can use it to walk in a straight line.